# How to get delivery date status on SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Using a T-SQL query:

1. How can I get the following status of shipment delivery date if it is:

   a. On-time delivery
   b. Early Delivery
   c. Late delivery
2. If custdate column is null, how can I do case query using Proddate column?
3. How to convert datetime of shipmentdate to date while using case statement?

I can get the status of item a and c

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
             (
                 ID INT,
                 ProdDate DATETIME,
                 CustDate DATETIME, 
                 ShipmentDate DATETIME
             )

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Proddate, CustDate, ShipmentDate)
VALUES (1, '2018-04-11', '2018-04-14', '2018-04-13 14:48'),
       (2, '2018-05-15', '2018-05-10', '2018-05-11 14:48'),
       (3, '2018-05-15', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-16 14:48'),
       (4, '2018-06-8', ' ', '2018-06-8 14:48'),
       (5, '2018-04-11', '2018-04-14', '2018-04-13 14:48'),
       (6, '2018-04-11', '2018-04-14', '2018-04-14 00:00')

SELECT 
    ID, proddate, custdate, shipmentdate,
    CASE 
       WHEN custdate = shipmentdate THEN 'ON TIME'
       WHEN custdate < shipmentdate THEN 'LATE'
    END AS status
FROM
    @tbl
```

I expect the following output:

```
1. Early
2. Late
3. On-Time (must convert to datetime to date format)
4. On-Time (based on proddate)
5.Early
6.On-Time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT ID, proddate,custdate,shipmentdate,
CASE 
WHEN CONVERT(DATE,isnull(NULLIF(custdate,''),ProdDate),101) = CONVERT(DATE,shipmentdate,101) then 'ON TIME'
WHEN CONVERT(DATE,isnull(NULLIF(custdate,''),ProdDate),101) < CONVERT(DATE,shipmentdate,101) then 'LATE'
WHEN CONVERT(DATE,isnull(NULLIF(custdate,''),ProdDate),101) > CONVERT(DATE,shipmentdate,101) then 'Early'
END AS STATUS
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Hi Do you know, how to convert this code into excel or power BI?

Comment: Hey @reborn, Sorry I don't know it in Excel or power BI.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(day, Shipmentdate, Custdate) = 0

COALESCE(CustDate, ProdDate)
```

I believe these are the two functions you are looking for. I am on my phone so forgive any typos.

DATEDIFF with the day parameter will compare the dates returning an integer of the difference in days, if they are the same day it returns 0.

COALESCE will return the first non null value.

Answer (score 0):

As your `ShipmentDate` contains date & time, you need to convert to `date` data type before compare.

Also for ID 4, you assigned an empty string to CustDate. That gets convert and store in table as `1900-01-01`.  It will be easier if you just store `NULL`. else you need to use a `case when` statement to check for `1900-01-01` value or `NULLIF()`. 
So to handle this based on your data, you use `isnull(nullif(CustDate, '1900-01-01'), ProdDate)` expression

```
CASE 
WHEN isnull(nullif(CustDate, '1900-01-01'), ProdDate) > convert(date, ShipmentDate) then 'EARLY'
WHEN isnull(nullif(CustDate, '1900-01-01'), ProdDate) = convert(date, ShipmentDate) then 'ON TIME'
WHEN isnull(nullif(CustDate, '1900-01-01'), ProdDate) < convert(date, ShipmentDate) then 'LATE'
end as status
```